# Classic ASP SQL Query Returns Two Columns Out Of Ten

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I'm hoping someone can help with a problem...I don't work in anything related to programming, but we needed some asset tracking pretty badly, so in my spare time (not very much, we average 10hrs days) and with the tools at hand (a 600mhz pile running winXP) i built a little classic ASP site to handle all the tracking and orders.

Everything was fine until I decided I had some more spare time and decided to upgrade a little.  The whole thing is pretty messy, but worst of its god awful slow.  So i decided to chuck my access db and JET drivers and go with MS SQL Server 2000 Express (don't forget, 600mhz and not much RAM).  I started rebuilding, and everything seemed to be working great (and much faster) until I started getting errors.  I figured out that for some queries, only a couple of the Columns would return any data.

**For Example**:  I have a shopitems table, with gID(uniqueID), iDesc(description), iLength, iQty, colID (cross reference).  I do a query to get everything in a certain catagory: `Select * from shopitems where catID=22 order by gID asc`.  Then i start stepping through and displaying it all.

The problem is, only gID and colID fields have data, everything else is nothing. I opened up the Web Data Administrator app and run the query in there, and it returns everything nice and fine.  So then i decided there is a bug somewhere, so I write a quick test page and same problem (except this time its gID and iLength that return data).  Its all a mix of data types, iDesc is nText and iLength is int.  I've gone through everything i can find, but i'm down to thinking its something i'm missing in SQL...anyone have any ideas?
Also, I replicated this on my throw away computer at home, which actually has a modern processor and decent amounts of RAM, so its not the machine at all.

Thanks for the help...i listen to the podcast and it seems like its been server/sql week for a while now, figured i'd ask someone here...

----EDIT----
Changed the code...a version of this code worked for a hot second, now not so much...if i comment out the

```
gID=rs1("gID")
```

then i get the value of iDesc, but not otherwise.

```
<%@ Language=vbscript %>
```

Damnit

```
Set db1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'db1.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Phsion;Database=master;"
db1.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=SHOPWEB;"
'sqltxt="select gID, iLength, iDesc from shopitems where catID=45 order by CAST(idesc as varchar)"

sqltxt="select iDesc, gID from ShopItems order by gID asc"
set rs1=db1.execute(sqltxt)
rs1.movefirst
do until rs1.eof
  gID=rs1("gID")
  'iLength=rs1("iLength")

  iDesc=rs1("iDesc")

  response.write("<br>gID: " & gid & "<br>")

  response.write("<br>iLength: " & iLength & "<br>")

  response.write("<br>iDesc: " & iDesc & "<br>")
  rs1.movenext
loop
rs1.close
set rs1=nothing
db1.close
set db1=nothing
```

Comment: Sorry, there you go...and yes, this is my first time using the site, and no, i have no idea why it chose to format my code for me in that manner

Comment: From the code you've posted it would appear that you've added the shopitems table to the master database.  You should create your own database and place your tables in there.

Comment: Consider also using an OLEDB provider connection string rather that this dated ODBC connection thunk.  See:- http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server#6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confusing problem.  Like mentioned, be sure to turn on option explicit to help find any variable name issues.  If you have used **On Error Resume Next** then you can use **On Error Goto 0** to make sure you aren't suppressing errors

Here is my take.  Break this into it's own file if you can for debugging.  If my loop produces output we can track things down.

```
<%
Option Explicit
On Error Goto 0

Dim db1, sqltxt, rs1
Dim gID, iLength, iDesc, arrRS

Set db1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'db1.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Phsion;Database=master;"
db1.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=SHOPWEB;"
'sqltxt="select gID, iLength, iDesc from shopitems where catID=45 order by CAST(idesc as varchar)"


'   sqltxt="select iDesc, gID from ShopItems order by gID asc"
'   set rs1=db1.execute(sqltxt)
'   rs1.movefirst
'   do until rs1.eof
'       gID = rs1("gID")
'       'iLength=rs1("iLength")
'       iDesc = rs1("iDesc")
'       response.write("gID: " & gid & "")
'       response.write("iLength: " & iLength & "")
'       response.write("iDesc: " & iDesc & "")
'       rs1.movenext
'   loop
'   rs1.close : set rs1=nothing

sqltxt="select iDesc, gID from ShopItems order by gID asc"
set rs1=db1.execute(sqltxt)
'//Dump the recordset into an array
arrRS = rs1.GetRows()
'//We can close the rs now since we don't need it anymore
rs1.close : set rs1=nothing

'//We are going to basically dump a HTML table that should look like you SQL viewer
Response.Write("<table>")
'//Loop through all the rows
For i = 0 To UBound(arrRS,2)
    Response.Write("<tr>")
    '//Loop through all the columns
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrRS,1)
            '//write out each column in the row
            Response.Write("<td>" & arrRS(j,i) & "</td>")
            '//Look I will be honest, I can't test this so your might have to swap the i and the j to get a full output
    Next
    Response.Write("</tr>")
Next
Response.Write("</table>")

db1.close : set db1=nothing
%>
```

Comment: OK...so yes, that works...on a side note, when i got overly frustrated, i upgraded from sql 2000 to 2005.  I still had the problem though...So what is my code doing thats so wacky?  Does SQL not believe me when I say I want everything out of the Database?  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, yes, your code was fine...except Option Explicit is still a pain in the ass, since 'i' and 'j' wern't declared

Comment: I am not too sure.  I would have to guess that it was a conflict between a variable used before the loop.  Your code as presented gave me no problems at all that I could tell, so it must be something else.

Comment: Did you use Option Explicit and DIM i and j, or did you stop using Option Explicit?

Comment: A little from column A, a little for column B...i used option explicit for laughs

Comment: Seems kinda like there is something between how the ADO object gets the info, and some difference between the JET DB driver and the SQL DB driver...all the info is there...if i use one method, i see the info, if i use another, i dont...where is the 'SQL Stop Trying To Make Me Faster' button?

Answer (score 3):

Add `Option Explicit` at the top (within <% and %>) to make variable declaration required, then declare your variables using `Dim variable-name-goes-here` for all your variables, and voila, you will see the problem right away.

Comment: +1, I didn't see your answer. I think it's a far better solution than just giving the solution right away like I did so I removed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you, instead of selecting everything (*), selects the required columns - do you still have the same problem? I.e:

```
SELECT gID, iDesc, iLength, iQty 
FROM shopitems
WHERE catID = 22
```

Comment: Nevermind, i'm an idiot, i thought i tried that but i left some debugging code in on accident which lied to me...Works perfect

Comment: Any reason why this would Fix it?

Comment: First now that you've removed the debugging code put the * back and confirm its yet again broken, then put the specific fields in to confirm that fixes it (and it is the correct approach).

Comment: Nah, its all kinds of broken again...i tried changing to sqltxt in the actual app, and its still broken, so then i tried the test page again, and now its broken too...so i slowly removed fields from the SELECT statement one at a time, and when i got down to two, it worked (kinda)

Comment: OK...so i have "select iDesc, gID from ShopItems order by gID asc" now.  If i comment out {gID=rs1("gID")} then i get a value for iDesc.  If i don't comment out the gID line, then i don't get iDesc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've fixed this yet, but if not then you should try changing the order you select your columns so that the nText field goes at the end.  There is a technical explanation for this (something to do with the maximum byte-length of a record, iirc).