# classic asp ado to stored proc drops fields depending on select order

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic, ado

I have to support a classic asp system (grrr) where it is returning nulls from a stored proc depending on the final select order in the proc.
I was managing to cope with this by just jiggling the select order until i got one that worked for every field...  Unfortunately now it has decided to work differently on different machines.

fairly basic asp:

```
' ORDER ITEMS
sSQL = "ProcName " & Order_ID

Dim iRowCount : iRowCount = 0
set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open Application("admin_ConnectionString") 

set rs = objConn.execute(sSQL)

if not rs.eof then
    ' Just doing this set thing to try and stop stupid ADO dropping fields !!
    ' The final select in the proc decides whether things will appear or disappear...
    set iQtyRequired = rs("QuantityRequired")

do until rs.eof 
   iQtyOutstanding  = iQtyRequired - iQtyFulfilled
```

SQL has a fair amount of processing WITH's, cursor and a final select:

```
SELECT  DispatchDate, ProposedDispatchQty, ...
FROM    @OrderItems
```

If i change the order of the select, different fields will "disappear" from ado - they are still there in .net and sql management studio.  I cant get any consistency as to which one causes it, seems to be many, i'll try 20 different combinations, get 20 different sets of blanks.

i guess ado is blowing up somewhere silently inside (date handling perhaps?).  Anyone got any good suggestions for getting some consistency?  (apart from rewriting it in c#)

Cheers in advance - Shane :)

Comment: Can you clarify: Can you change the proc to return 0 instead of Nulls? Why don't you just check if the field is null: if not isnull(rs("QuantityRequired")) then ...

Comment: I think you are missing the point - there is data there (profile sql - run in mgmt studio) but then it is dropped by ?ado.

Comment: Ok i gave up - tried renaming all variables on the page in case there was some kind of scope issue - no change so i ripped out the part of the proc that i needed for the page, copied it into a new one and voila !  issue gone !

Answer (score 1):

I've already faced that kind of issue in the past when working with ntext columns. I had to select the ntext column last and that would do the job. Changing your connection string can also help.

Check out this question, quite the same problem as yours : [SQL Server text column affects results returned to classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673680/sql-server-text-column-affects-results-returned-to-classic-asp)

Comment: Thx for that - no ntext columns varchar(max) be the closest but it is using ODBC.  I'll put it back to broken and test the connection.

Comment: I had this with a TEXT column too. If the ASP accessed the recordset fields in the right order (the TEXT one last), you could get by without changing the order of columns in the SELECT. Weird!