# Losing my recordset values

Tags: asp-classic

Each field returned in this stored procedure has a value but when I write out the values some of them are blank. Any ideas?

```
Dim objConn
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=db","test","test"

Set emailCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
emailCMD.ActiveConnection = objconn
emailCMD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
emailCMD.CommandText = "get_email"

emailCMD.Parameters.Append(emailCMD.CreateParameter("userid",adInteger,adParamInput,,userid))
emailCMD.Parameters.Append(emailCMD.CreateParameter("emailaddress",adVarChar,adParamInput,100,emailaddress))
emailCMD.Parameters.Append(emailCMD.CreateParameter("emailjobid",adInteger,adParamInput,,emailjobid))
emailCMD.Parameters.Append(emailCMD.CreateParameter("businessid",adInteger,adParamInput,,businessid))

Set emailrs = emailCMD.Execute

emailbody = emailRS("emailjobdesc")
sendto = emailrs("emailaddress")
emailsubject = emailrs("emailjobsubject")   
emailid = emailrs("emailid")
emailpassword = emailrs("emailpassword")
businessname = emailrs("businessname")  

response.write emailbody & "<br>" & sendto & "<br>"&emailsubject&"<br>"&emailid&"<br>"&emailpassword&"<br>"&businessname
response.End
```

Comment: Is it always the same fields that are blank?

Comment: If you are finding that emailbody and sento are populated and the others are blank, try putting spaces around all the & characters.

Comment: Please post the code of the stored procedure - if the fields are populated by successive statements, you have to use `NextRecordset` method to reach them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it

Replace:

```
Set emailrs = emailCMD.Execute
```

With

```
Set emailRS = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
emailrs.cursorlocation = adUseClient
emailrs.open emailCMD
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same problem.
mysql odbc 5.1 driver.

Solved by changing [cursorlocation](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_conn_cursorlocation.asp) property in a connection object.

```
set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.cursorlocation = 3 ''adUseClient
Connection.Open ConnStr
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some output or ReturnValue parameters for the fields you wish to extract from the database.

http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13399

Comment: I think the OP is reading from the result set, not from the parameters.

Comment: I'm returning 1 row in my stored procedure. For some reason it's blowing up. If I return the data in output parameters it works. Why does it blow up with just 1 row?

Comment: "If I return the data in output parameters it works."  So what is the problem with using output parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure get_email is returning 6 columns - are any of these columns Text/NText? (and you're hooked up to a SQL Server 2000 database?)

Change your connection string - don't use ODBC.

If you change the order of the returned columns so that the text column is last, this will probably fix your issue. I've had this problem a lot in the past, and listing the text column at the end of the select list always fixed the problem.

I asked this question a couple of years ago
[SQL Server text column affects results returned to classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673680/sql-server-text-column-affects-results-returned-to-classic-asp) and having changed my connection string to Microsoft OLE DB Provider haven't had any problems since.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested if the table field contains datatype which is varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) will appear this problem.

The work around solution is to put

Connection.cursorlocation = 3 'adUseClient

as mentioned above by the other answer or to reduce the size of the nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(999)