# MS SQL Server 2012 returning blank text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, odbc

I execute this inside MS SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM searchdb.dbo.tblnames;
```

I get back two posts with full information.

When I execute the same on a webpage I however get all information *except* for text, which is blank.

The type of the text columns in the database are:

```
ntext
```

The connection string I'm using:

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=searchdb;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass;
```

I've also tried with:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=localhost;Database=searchdb;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass;
```

Getting the same result. I don't know the difference between "SQL Server" and "SQL Server Native Client 11.0", just that "SQL Server" has a newer date in the list of ODBC Data Sources.

What's going on? **Why is it returning blank text?** How do I fix this?

Edit: Here is the code I'm using on the ASP web pages:

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=searchdb;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass;"

Set RecSet = Conn.Execute("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM tblnames;")
    Response.Write "ID: "& RecSet("ID") &"<br>"
    Response.Write "Name: "& RecSet("name") &"<br>"
    Response.Write "Mark: "& RecSet("mark") &"<br>"
    RecSet.MoveNext
    Response.Write "ID: "& RecSet("ID") &"<br>"
    Response.Write "Name: "& RecSet("name") &"<br>"
    Response.Write "Mark: "& RecSet("mark") &"<br>"
Set RecSet = Nothing
```

Both the ID and Mark columns have "int" data type and show up fine, while the "name" column is blank.

Edit 2:

```
Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question
for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 3/15/2014 4:16:50 AM. Until
then please use comments, or edit your question instead.
```

It's dumb that you have to make an account on stackoverflow (didn't have to before), and that you can't answer your own questions on a new account. And I hope some mod doesn't edit this post. If things are wrong with your system it's important that people can point it out.

Anyways, here is the answer:

**Self-answered:**

I changed my connection string to:

```
Provider=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;Server=localhost;Database=searchdb;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass;
```

Now everything works fine.

I have no idea why it didn't work correctly when I used that one as "Driver" but whatever. Note that just "Provider=SQL Server" didn't work at all, while "Driver={SQL Server}" worked exactly the same as "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}" (that is, with blank text).

No idea how Provider is different than Driver. "Provider" isn't even mentioned anywhere in Control Panel > Administrative Tools > ODBC Data Sources.

After some testing it seems like both Driver and Provider is just as fast as each other too, so there's no benefit from using Driver, it is just broken.

Comment: Show the code you are using to display the contents of the nText column.

Comment: As a side note, please don't use `ntext` it's been deprecated for years now and exists only for backwards compatibility. Use `nvarchar(max)` instead if you need

Comment: I'm using old ASP code which was using the old Access database, finally thought it was time to change to a modern database. After a lot of headache with MySQL I settled with MS SQL. The reason I'm using ntext is because I let Access automatically convert itself to MSSQL with their wizard. I would rather not have to go through all fields manually and change ntext to nvarchar. Is it really that important? If yes, why and is there a way to do it automatically? Will post ASP code in a moment, hang on.

Comment: Code has been added, I don't think there's anything faulty there. Especially since it worked on the Access databases.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like changing your query to use a column list, rather than the asterisk, could take care of the issue. Also, I read that your ntext field should be the last column in your list. Seems strange, but it's worth a shot.

**Resources:**

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-deal-with-memo-text-hyperlink-and-currency-columns.html

[SQL Server text column affects results returned to classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673680/sql-server-text-column-affects-results-returned-to-classic-asp)

***EDIT:***

You also might try converting the ntext to an nvarchar in your sql statement.

```
SELECT TOP 2 ID, Mark, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Name) [Name] FROM tblNames
```

Comment: That didn't help. I don't get it, how can it be like this?

Comment: It's definitely strange. Take a look at my edit and see if that works.

Comment: I just added my own solution, just had to change the connection string. I would have posted it as an answer but the retarded system of stackoverflow doesnt allow new accounts to do that. Thanks for all your help though asch, I appreaciate it!

Comment: @user3421413 The limitation is there for good reasons, but I think your can answer your own question after 8 hours? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is